# How to use a Wizard Extension for Item Templates

Tags: c#, itemtemplate

I am trying to setup an Item Template where the .vstemplate file contains a reference (WizardExtension) to a .DLL that implements a form to collect custom parameters for the template.  I used a Project Template having an example for implementing the Form Wizard, but when I select my template from the Add New... page, I get an error dialog saying:
"Error: this template attempted to load component assembly 'MyWizard, version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxx'."
Does anyone know how I can setup the Item Template to use a form for collecting custom parameters ?

Comment: Have you tried to check this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-use-wizards-with-project-templates?view=vs-2022 ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this solution: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-use-wizards-with-project-templates?view=vs-2022

Especially clauses 10, 11 and 12. Also, there are examples included as well.

> 10. Extract the public key from the key.snk file. In the command window,
>     type
>
> \sn.exe -p key.snk outfile.key.
>
> Don't forget to surround the path of sn.exe with quotation marks if
> there are spaces in the directory names!

> 11. Get the public key token from the outfile:
>
> < location of sn.exe >\sn.exe -t outfile.key.
>
> Again, don't forget the quotation marks. You should see a line in the
> output like this>
> Public key token is < token >>
> Make a note of this value.
>
> 12. Add the reference to the custom wizard to the .vstemplate file of the
>     project template. In the Solution Explorer, find the file named
>     MyProjectTemplate.vstemplate, and open it. After the end of the
>      section, add the following section:

```
<WizardExtension>
    <Assembly>MyProjectWizard, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=token</Assembly>
    <FullClassName>MyProjectWizard.WizardImplementation</FullClassName>
</WizardExtension>
```

> Where MyProjectWizard is the name of the assembly, and token is the
> token you copied in the previous step.